# Creating SQL database. with multiple primary and foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently working through an assignment that is asking me to create a SQL database using SQL Server Express. This is what it's asking for:
[CREATE DATABASE USING SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5UY8.png)

And this is the code I have tried running;

```
CREATE DATABASE db_Library
Go

USE db_Library

CREATE TABLE tbl_library_branch 
(
    library_branch_branch_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
    library_branch_branch_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    library_branch_address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_publisher 
(
    library_publisher_publisher_name VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    library_publisher_address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    library_publisher_phone INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_books 
(
    library_books_book_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
    library_books_title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    library_books_publisher_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_library_books_publisher_name FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tbl_publisher(library_publisher_publisher_name) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_book_authors 
(
    library_book_authors_book_id INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_library_book_authors_book_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tbl_books(library_books_book_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    library_book_authors_author_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_book_copies 
(
    library_book_copies_book_id INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_library_book_copies_book_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tbl_books(library_books_title),
    library_book_copies_branch_id INT NOT NULL,
    library_book_copies_number_of_copies INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_book_loans 
(
    library_book_loans_book_id INT NOT NULL,
    library_book_loans_branch_id INT NOT NULL,
    library_book_loans_card_no INT NOT NULL,
    library_book_loans_date_out INT NOT NULL,
    library_book_loans_date_due INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_borrower 
(
    library_borrower_card_no INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
    library_borrower_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    library_borrower_address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    library_borrower_phone VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Using the library "Books" as an example it looks like I need to have BoodID as a primary key and Title as a primary key, but you can't have more than one primary key per table..

Then I have to take BookID from the Book_Copies table and the Book_Loans table connect to the primary key of Title in Books?

I'm beyond stuck at this point and would appreciate any resources you think could help.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're referring to.  You don't have any tables with multiple primary keys in the example.  You have tables with a primary key and a _foreign_ key relationship.  Is that where you're stuck?

Comment: Think about it: Title can't be a primary key for a book because many books can have the same title.

Comment: @Honeyboy Wilson I see what your saying. Basically I was shown very briefly how to create a primary key and link to a foreign key. After that I was asked to do this. I'm assuming Title isn't a primary key and I can somehow link multiple different libraries to it. I'm just trying to figure out how to do so. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @squillman Basically I was shown very briefly how to create a primary key and link to a foreign key. After that I was asked to do this. I just feel like there is a bit of information they left out and assumed I would figure it out. I think I just don't understand how to take Title from Books and link it twice to BookID in both Book_Copies and Book_Loans. I tried to make Title in Books a primary and link via foreign keys to both bookID in both Book_Copies and Book-Loans. Obviously that's not going to work though.

Comment: BookID connects those tables, not Title.

Comment: Do yourself and future generations a favor. While naming conventions are debatable and personal, there is no reason to preface every table name with "tbl". And your assignment tells you the names of the tables - so why did you make those names FAR longer? You (and others) will have to type those names over and over and over - make it easier! There is also little point to preface column names with the name of the table. Best practices (which you need to learn/follow) will always make the source of any column very clear.

Comment: @SMor Trust me. I agree. I have a good mentor and he was looking over the code and noted the same thing. Issue is we are provided a template that names the tables and columns that way. I've tried changing them and I'll see if the instructor brings it up. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to be so verbose.  I think you want something more like this (for two tables):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_publisher (
    publisher_id int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    publisher_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    phone INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE books (
    book_id INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    publisher_id INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_books_publisher__id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tbl_publisher(publisher_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Notes:

- Stick with synthetic primary keys for all the tables.  That is, `identity` columns.
- Other columns can be declared to be `unique`.  That is fine.
- I type quite fast.  And yet I would quickly wary of typing `library_book_` over and over.  Such repetition just makes it harder to write and read queries.